Logarithmic Integral
I am trying to solve the following definite integral for some arbitrary $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ (where $0 < c < a < b$):
$$\int_a^b \frac{1}{(x - c)\log(x)} \ \mathrm{d}x$$
How would I approach an integral like this? Does this integral even have a solution in terms of elementary and special functions?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

\begin{align}
\int_a^b \frac{1}{(x - c)\log(x)} dx &= \int_a^b \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{c^k}{x^{k+1}\log(x)} dx\\
&=\int_a^b\frac{1}{x\log(x)}dx+ \sum_{k=1}^\infty c^k\int_a^b\frac{1}{x^{k+1}\log(x)}dx\\
&=\left.\log(\log(x))\right|_a^b+\sum_{k=1}^\infty c^k\left(\left.\text{Li}(x^{-k})\right|_a^b\right)\\
&=\log(\log(b))-\log(\log(a))+\sum_{k=1}^\infty c^k\left(\text{Li}(b^{-k})-\text{Li}(a^{-k})\right)
\end{align}
where $\text{Li}(x)$ is the Logarithmic Integral function.

From my understanding, the domain of Li is [2, inf) but b^-k <= 1 if b > 1. So do I need to use li instead of Li?

@adpad Just because $\text{Li}(x)$ is defined as $\int_2^x \frac{dt}{\log(t)}$ doesn't mean that its domain is $[2,\infty)$. A similar thing happens with the $\log$ function, there are several ways to define it, one of them being $\int_1^x\frac{dt}{t}$, but that doesn't mean that the domain of $\log$ is $[1,\infty)$.

@adpad The domain of $\text{Li}$ (as a real function) is $[0,\infty)\setminus{1}$ (where the Cauchy principal value must be taken for the integral when $x\in[0,1)$. )

Thank you for the clarification!

for: $0<c<a<b$
$$\int_a^b \frac{1}{(x-c) \log (x)} \, dx=\\\int_a^b \frac{\int_0^{\infty } x^{-t} \, dt}{x-c} \, dx=\\\int_0^{\infty } \left(\int_a^b \frac{x^{-t}}{x-c} \, dx\right) \, dt=\\\int_0^{\infty } c^{-t}
   \left(B_{\frac{c}{a}}(t,0)-B_{\frac{c}{b}}(t,0)\right) \, dt=\\\int_0^{\infty } c^{-t} \left(\frac{\left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^t \,
   _2F_1\left(1,t;1+t;\frac{c}{a}\right)}{t}-\frac{\left(\frac{c}{b}\right)^t \, _2F_1\left(1,t;1+t;\frac{c}{b}\right)}{t}\right) \, dt=\\\int_0^{\infty } c^{-t} \left(\frac{\left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^t
   \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^m (1)_m (t)_m}{m! (1+t)_m}}{t}-\frac{\left(\frac{c}{b}\right)^t \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(\frac{c}{b}\right)^m (1)_m (t)_m}{m!
   (1+t)_m}}{t}\right) \, dt=\\\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \int_0^{\infty } c^{-t} \left(\frac{\left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^{m+t}}{m+t}-\frac{\left(\frac{c}{b}\right)^{m+t}}{m+t}\right) \, dt=\\\sum _{m=0}^{\infty
   } c^m (\text{Ei}(-m \log (a))-\text{Ei}(-m \log (b)))=\\-\frac{1}{2} \left(-\log \left(-\frac{1}{\log (a)}\right)+\log (-\log (a))+\log \left(-\frac{1}{\log (b)}\right)-\log (-\log (b))\right)-\sum
   _{m=1}^{\infty } c^m \text{Ei}(-m \log (a))+\sum _{m=1}^{\infty } c^m \text{Ei}(-m \log (b))$$
where: $\text{Ei}$ is exponential integral function.

You need to deal with the term for $m=0$ separately.
